# Getting only specific data from controller

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I am passing Json string to service Home/GetAllAttendanceData and i want to retrieve it in controller.here is my  code..

```
    public JsonResult GetAllAttendanceData()
    {
        var ab = (from obj in db.Attendances where obj.Id==1 select new {EmpNTLogin = obj.EmpNTLogin });
        return this.Json(ab,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

## Heading ##
 angular.module('myModule', []).service("crudAJService", function ($http) {
        this.getdata = function () {
            return $http.get("Home/GetAllAttendanceData");
        };
    }).controller('myController', function ($scope, crudAJService) {
        $scope.divBook = false;
        GetAlldata();
        function GetAlldata() {
            debugger;
            var getAttendanceData = crudAJService.getdata();

            getAttendanceData.then(function (Attendances) {

                $scope.Attendancesdata = Attendances.data
                alert($scope.Attendancesdata);
            }, function () {
                alert('Error in getting book records');
            });
        }
    });
```

I want to display the string in  alert($scope.Attendancesdata);

Comment: what do you get now, what is exactly the problem?

Comment: In alert($scope.Attendancesdata), it shows [object] [object]

Comment: i want to retrieve the string which I passed in above C# code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe what you want is this:

```
alert(JSON.stringify($scope.Attendancesdata));
```

Comment: thanks buddy...it works for me..may i know how to retrieve similarly an array passed